# How to display values *only* at every x steps

Tags: c++, loops, iteration, counter

I'm trying to finish up a program which calculates the natural logarithm of 2, based on the desired # of terms to use and how many values to display after every x step. For example if the user inputs 6 terms, displaying them every 2 steps it would have this output;

0.5000000000

0.5833333333

0.6166666667

instead of:

1.0000000000

0.5000000000

0.8333333333

0.5833333333

0.7833333333

0.6166666667

This loop doesn't work correctly for what I'm trying to do and I'm trying to find out what adjustments to make for it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
    for(double x = 1; x <= numofterms; x += 1){

    logarithm += denominator * 1 / x;
    denominator = -denominator;

    int printCounter = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=numofterms; i++) {
    printCounter++;
      if(printCounter >= displaycount) {
         cout << setprecision(10) << showpoint << logarithm << endl;
         printCounter = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Adding a "bool show = false;" before your loop, evaluating the flag inside the loop to do the cout and doing a "show = !show;" should be enough.

Comment: Another possibility is to just use the loop counter, something like: `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) if (i % 2 == 0) print(current_value);`

Comment: Use `if(printcmounter % displaycount == 0)` instead.

Comment: why do you need double for loop ? just remove the second for loop it will work, dont forget to add the mising brace }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that can do it:

```
int curPrintStep = displayCount;
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfterms ; i++) {
    logarithm += denominator * 1 / (double) i;
    denominator = -denominator;

    if (i == curPrintStep) {
        cout << setprecision(10) << showpoint << logarithm << endl;

        curPrintStep += displayCount;
    }
}
```

The variable i contains the current step of the algorithm and at the same time is used to calculate the logarithm.

I set up a step counter variable `curPrintStep` which is set to the first printing step. Every time I check and if the current step is equal to the print step, I print the logarithm and change the `curPrintStep` to point to the next print step (by adding `displayCount` to it).

Answer (score 2):

You are using `printCounter >= displaycount` which is wrong

Lets say `printCounter` is 100 and  `displaycount` is 20  so you should get 6 lines, but after `printCounter` reaches 20 it will display for every line so you get 81 lines.

So better use `printCounter % displaycount == 0` this will only show the lines for `0,20,40,60,80,100` value of `printCounter`

Comment: He does a `printCounter = 0;` -- but it is not clear from the formatting and `{}` if that is inside or outside of the if statement.

Comment: why he needs double for loop ?